# Saving metadata per frame. What format to use?

Tags: formats, metadata

I am building some software that does analysis of video. Each frame has metadata associated with it. We save the video so we can play it back later. We would like to be able to play it back with that metadata association (perhaps displaying the info overlayed on the video for instance).

**What do you think is the best way to store this information?** I was thinking MKV could be used, as it naturally has a concept of tracks. If it helps, I am using GStreamer for all my video manipulation

Comment: Welcome! I'm not sure you are going to get good answers here since your question is borderline off topic and is opinion based. That said, there really is no standard for metadata transport and it would depend on your audience. We would need more details. For a professional application, MXF, IMF, or even Quicktime might be better.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for commenting. What about it is offtopic? Is there anything to do to improve the question?

Comment: The off topic aspect is that your question is related to developing software that uses media, compared to making media that uses software. But it is a grey area. For improvements, a few questions off the top of my head: Who is your target audience? What is the metadata? Will it be consumed by other systems?